# Explain sparse representation in relate to generalization?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Is there a relation between sparse representation (such as: one-hot encoder) and generalization. Kindly explain.

This is in relate to: section 13.2 of "Learning Deep Architectures for AI" by Yoshua Bengio.